# Android - AOSP - WorkManager runtime error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/R$bool

Tags: java, android, android-source

I have built an android app that makes use of WorkManager.
I'm now trying to build this as a system app as part of and android 9.1 AOSP project.

I have managed to get the app to build, but it is throwing runtime errors:

```
    Process: MyApp, PID: 4959
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/R$bool;
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.<init>(WorkManagerImpl.java:210)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.initialize(WorkManagerImpl.java:186)
        at androidx.work.WorkManager.initialize(WorkManager.java:204)
        at MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:24)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5885)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1651)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.R$bool" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/MyApp/MyApp.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/MyApp/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

I'm assuming I need to pull something else in for it to resolve `androidx.work.R`?

Just to reiterate, the same app works when build as a standalone gradle build and deployed to the same platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

My `Android.mk` looks like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DX_FLAGS := --multi-dex

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    work-runtime-prebuilt \
    room-runtime-prebuilt \
    guava

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    androidx.appcompat_appcompat

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)


# Prebuilt Java Libraries required by the app
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    work-runtime-prebuilt:libs/work-runtime-2.3.4.aar \
    room-runtime-prebuilt:libs/room-runtime-2.2.5.aar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

As you can see, I have pulled in `work-runtime-2.3.4.aar` and its dependent `room-runtime-2.2.5.aar` as it was throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` exception.

I also had to disable the `WorkManagerInitializer` in the manifest like this:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="MyApp.workmanager-init"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" />
```

And initialize it in my `Application` class instead

```
import androidx.work.Configuration;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        WorkManager.initialize(this, new Configuration.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

For reference, my `build.gradle` has:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1' // To match the platform version
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4'
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the .gradle/caches/files-2.1/androidx.work folder and do a clean and build.

Comment: It works when built with gradle. The AOSP build does not use gradle, it's a soong build using Android.mk file, all the dependencies are included in the source tree, so no cache to delete. The separate .arr I downloaded from a maven repo and added to the build tree

Comment: @SimonWilliams Have you found any solution?

Comment: @ziLk Unfortunately not, I'm currently building an apk in Android Studio via gradle and then including the apk in the AOSP build

Comment: @SimonWilliams it makes sense!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Working on AOSP build . Build is successfull.Getting RunTime error.I think issue with Android.bp configuration.

Comment: Gradle automatically resolves the dependencies, and pulls in the deps from repositories.

I believe there might be more than just a 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.4' AAR needed.